# How to delay with use of keyevent?

Tags: java, delay, keyevent

I want that when I press and hold space button that the spaceship's bullets shoot every 2 seconds. Now if I press and hold space button the spaceship shoots lots of bullets in one line. How can I fix this?

Method in class `Game`

```java
public void newBullet() {                 
    Bullet k = new Bullet(this.spaceship.getX() + (Spaceship.WIDTH / 2), this.spaceship.getY() - 15, DEFAULT_SPEED,type.SPACESHIP);
    bullets.add(k);
}
```

---

```java
public class ShootBullet extends TimerTask {
    private Game model;
    private SpaceInvadersController controller;
    
    public ShootBullet(Game model, SpaceInvadersController controller) {
        this.model = model;
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();             
        final double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        final double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        while(true){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1) {
                this.model.tick();
                Platform.runLater(controller::update);
                delta--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is in controller:

```java
private void move(KeyEvent k) {
    switch(k.getCode()){
        case LEFT:
            this.model.spaceshipLeft();
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            this.model.spaceshipRight();
            break;
        case UP:
            this.model.spaceshipUp();
            break;
        case DOWN:                     
            this.model.spaceshipDown();
            break;
        case SPACE:
            this.shoot();
            break;
    }
    view.update();      
}

private void shoot() {
    ShootBullet task = new ShootBullet(this.model, this);
    this.model.newBullet();
    timer2.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);
    update();
}
```

Comment: Consider posting a [mcve]. Also, I think you should be using a [_Swing_ timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: Don’t run the task in a thread. It seems every time you press space a new task in put at into the threadpool queue. That is the issue why so many bullets are fired. You need to check if you are already shooting. Further you need to consider KEY_PRESSED events

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation for [KeyEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html). You will notice there are three types of events:

- KEY_PRESSED
- KEY_TYPED (is only generated if a valid Unicode character could be generated.)
- KEY_RELEASED

The KEY_TYPED events are the problematic ones for you, since they are generated by the hardware/keyboard driver according to operating system settings. You cannot change the rate at which they fire.

But you can completely ignore them and go for KEY_PRESSED and KEY_RELEASED. So as soon as you notice a KEY_PRESSED event, start your timer that will fire at the rate you want, and stop that timer when you receive a KEY_RELEASED.